# EJB3 Transaction management vs Spring Transaction management

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ejb

Can anyone tell me if there are any essential differences in transaction management between  Spring and EJB3? For example, we have two beans:

```
@Stateless
class BeanBImpl implements BeanB {

    methodB(){
       ...
    }
}
@Stateless
class BeanAImpl implements BeanA {

    @EJB
    BeanB beanB;

    methodA(){
        ...
        beanB.methodB();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I know that when `methodA()` will be executed, by default EJB container will "share" transaction between `methodA()` and `methodB()` so that if rollback will ocure, changes from both methods will be rollbacked. However, does the Spring provides the same functionality?
Moreover, does the exception handling work the same in both containers?
Are there any other releven differences?